# How to set a value on a Lead object field given its a value in a Map key?

Tags: apex

If you see my code below, setting the status in the last line doesn't work?

```
Map<String, Object> courses = new Map<String, Object> {
                 'nutrition' => new Map<String, Object> {
                     'status' => leadInstance.Nutrition_Purchase_Status__c,
                     'date' => leadInstance.Advanced_Nutrition_Date__c
                  }
        };

        for (String keyName : courses.keySet()) {
            Map<String, Object> course = (Map<String, Object>) courses.get(keyName);
            Object status = course.get('status');
            status = 'Prize Winner';

        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to set `course.status`?

Comment: Yes, initially I'll do course.status == 'Free Trial' and if yes, then I'll set it to some other string. But that doesn't work. It only get's the string value, won't let me set it.

Comment: Are these `Map<String, Object>` structures supposed to represent `SObject` records? If so you would be way better off using the records themselves instead of this convoluted structure.

Comment: Yes but I have 20 of these courses, so using many if else statements is really bad. I want to basically make it more scalable like this and helps test coverage a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works. Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction.

```
   Map<String, Object> courses = new Map<String, Object> {
             'nutrition' => new List<String> {
                 'Nutrition_Purchase_Status__c',
                 'Advanced_Nutrition_Date__c'
              }
    };

    for (String keyName : courses.keySet()) {
        List<String> course = (List<String>) courses.get(keyName);
        leadInstance.put(course[0], 'Subscription');
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the course values in a for loop rather than referencing the element via course[0]?

Comment: This is because for now its simple. I just need to loop over all courses, see if they are on a free trial and then upon some logic, I set them to subscription, in addition to setting other stuff. Works for now. But good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `course.status`, you need to use:

```
((Map<String, Object>)courses.get(keyName)).put('status', 'Prize Winner');
```

As for your `Map` structure, just guessing but... it would probably be much better to use a `Map<String, SObject>`. Assuming your object name is `Course__c`, for instance:

```
Map<String, Course__c> courseMap = new Map<String, Course__c>
{
    'Nutrition': new Course__c(Status__c=somestatus1, Date__c=someDate1),
    'SomeOtherCourse: new Course__c(/*etc*/)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one doesn't work. It doesn't set anything. And as for the second one, I am supplying the lead object in a function from somewhere else. So I am not creating a new object, but accessing field data on an existing one and based on logic, amending its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to update the value of status in the Map, why don't you just override the value like below

```
    for (String keyName : courses.keySet()) {
        Map<String, Object> course = (Map<String, Object>) courses.get(keyName);
        Object status = course.get('status');
        course.put('status','Prize Winner'); // This will override the existing status value in the map
    }
```

Edit : Update your original Map like this:

```
    Map<String, Object> courses = new Map<String, Object> {
                 'nutrition' => new Map<String, Object> {
                 'Lead' => leadInstance,
                 'date' => leadInstance.Advanced_Nutrition_Date__c
           }
    };

    for (String keyName : courses.keySet()) {
        Map<String, Object> course = (Map<String, Object>) courses.get(keyName);
        sObject leadInstaceFromMap = (sObject) course.get('Lead');
        leadInstaceFromMap.set('Nutrition_Purchase_Status__c','New Status');

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it doesn't update. If I do directly like `leadInstance.Nutrition_Purchase_Status__c = 'Prize Winner'` that works.

Comment: You are not maintaining any reference for leadInstance record in your map.

Comment: Marty, that's not scalable. I have 20 courses., @Salesforcesmarty gives me this too : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SObject].set(String, String)

Comment: What difference does it make if you have 20 courses? Additionally why can't you use a class to replicate the map behavior. Something like below :

Public Class Courses{
    sObject Nutrition;
    sObject Lead;
    String Status;
    String Date;
}